# geom_dotplot fill aesthetic changes data grouping

Tags: r, ggplot2

Adding a fill variable to `geom_dotplot` introduces an unwanted grouping to the geom. Here's the behavior when you don't add a fill variable:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
 ggplot(
   aes(
     factor(vs), mpg
   )
 ) +
 geom_dotplot(
   stackdir = "center", 
   binaxis = "y", 
   fill = "white"
 ) +
 coord_flip()
```

returns

[image: no fill dotplot]

I just want to color some dots, for attention purposes, but I don't want the dots to change location. If I try to affect the fill as follows:

```
mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column %>% 
  mutate(
    merc = rowname %>%
      str_detect("Merc ") %>%
      as.numeric %>%
      factor
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(
      factor(vs), mpg, fill = merc
    )
  ) +
  geom_dotplot(
    stackdir = "center", 
    binaxis = "y", 
  ) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none"
  )
```

returns

[image]

I want the dots to stay where they are in the first plot, but introduce a fill aesthetic. Is this possible in `geom_dotplot`?

Comment: The things is geom_dotplot is doing some count base on group variable and with the group of merc (1 vs 0) the statistic is change so you can't have the same plot as non-grouping. Hope I explain it clear enough.

Comment: It won't be identical, but you might want the `binpositions = "all",` parameter in `geom_dotplot` to get a more consistent appearance with your original.

Comment: @JonSpring -- that's a huge improvement. if you write it up as the answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two of the `geom_dotplot` options might be useful here:

binpositions

> When method is "dotdensity", "bygroup" (default)
> determines positions of the bins for each group separately. "all"
> determines positions of the bins with all the data taken together;
> this is used for aligning dot stacks across multiple groups.

stackgroups

> should dots be stacked across groups? This has the effect that
> position = "stack" should have, but can't (because this geom has some
> odd properties).

```
... + geom_dotplot(alpha = 0.6,   # for testing to show overplotting - none here
                   binpositions = "all", 
                   stackgroups = TRUE,  # to avoid overplotting
                   stackdir = "center", 
                   binaxis = "y", 
      )
```

[image]